# Why the components get rendered twice in default.vue layout?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I am creating web app with nuxt composition api. In my layouts, first components get rendered twice even if i change order of components.

**default.vue**

```
.layout-default
  header(showLanguage :langUrl="langUrl")
  mobile-header(:class="{ 'sticky-header': isSticky }")
  section.main-menu(v-for="menu in menuList")
    .main-category
      .flex
        .menu-content.relative.container
          header-menu(:items="menu.main.title" :visible="true")
          ys-breaking-news
          ys-weather-pray

  finance
  nuxt(keep-alive)
  .w-full.flex(v-observe-visibility="visibilityChanged")
    .flex.container(v-if="isVisibleRef")
      footer
  ys-modal.login-modal.login-successull.login-toast(ref="successModal")
   toast(ref="successRef" width="50" @closeToast="closeSuccessToast")
```

**result of console.logs in Mounted**

```
header mount
header mount
breaking news
weather mount
```

First component was rendered 2 times.
This happens when i refreshed page. If i switch to deafult.vue layout from another page or layout, it will render one time .

Comment: We don't have enough context here.

Comment: i added some context

Comment: Not really relevant to the context IMO. You don't have any errors? Maybe a public github repo?